# Dual boot Arch and Windows 10 with GRUB

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot, grub, arch-linux

I've been using Ubuntu for a while and recently decided to start using Arch. I have both a 120GB SSD and 1TB HDD in my system. When installing Arch on my SSD, I created partitions for /boot /home / (root) as well as a swap partition. I also have Windows 10 installed on my HDD using the default partitions. I would like to be able to dual boot between the 2 operating systems. I installed GRUB to my SSD on /dev/sda, but now when I boot into GRUB, I only see the option to boot into Arch, not Windows. I was wondering how I could boot into Windows via GRUB.

I have a default "/etc/grub.d/40_custom" file:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries
.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be care
ful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
```

When I run "lsblk", I get:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 111.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   200M  0 part /boot
├─sda2   8:2    0    12G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda3   8:3    0    25G  0 part /
└─sda4   8:4    0  74.6G  0 part /home
sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   499M  0 part 
├─sdb2   8:18   0   100M  0 part 
├─sdb3   8:19   0    16M  0 part 
└─sdb4   8:20   0 930.9G  0 part
```

Running "fdisk -l" gives me:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 47A5839B-C531-4BEE-A083-BD0C5CF4524A

Device       Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1     2048    1023999    1021952   499M Windows rec
/dev/sdb2  1024000    1228799     204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sdb3  1228800    1261567      32768    16M Microsoft r
/dev/sdb4  1261568 1953523711 1952262144 930.9G Microsoft b


Disk /dev/sda: 111.8 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x1c797ba1

Device     Boot    Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1           2048    411647    409600  200M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2         411648  25577471  25165824   12G 83 Linux
/dev/sda3       25577472  78006271  52428800   25G 83 Linux
/dev/sda4       78006272 234441647 156435376 74.6G 83 Linux
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: have you tried `sudo update-grub`?

Comment: When I try to run that command on Arch, it says that the command cannot be found. According to this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111889/how-do-i-update-grub-in-arch-linux, the "# update-grup" command is referring to "# grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg" I've tried to run this command and it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Then you should try with grub2 `sudo grub2-mkconfig`

Comment: Thanks for the help, I managed to fix it by fixing my MBR

Answer (score 2):

As described [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Windows_installed_in_UEFI.2FGPT_Mode_menu_entry), you need to do the following (The following must be done as root on your Arch OS):

As I can assume from your Output `/dev/sdb2` seems to be your Windows-Bootloader so the First step will be:

```
$ mkdir /mnt/windows
$ mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt/windows
$ grub-probe --target=fs_uuid /mnt/windows/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
```

Copy the Output of the last Command to a File and proceed with this:

```
$ grub-probe --target=hints_string /mnt/windows/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
```

Also copy the output to the File. After that run the following to unmount the Partition

```
$ umount /mnt/windows
$ rmdir /mnt/windows
```

After that open the File `/boot/grub/custom.cfg` with your preferred editor and add the Following Lines:

```
if [ "${grub_platform}" == "efi" ]; then
    menuentry "Microsoft Windows Vista/7/8/8.1 UEFI/GPT" {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod fat
        insmod search_fs_uuid
        insmod chain
        search --fs-uuid --set=root $hints_string $fs_uuid
        chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
    }
fi
```

Where `$hints_string` is the second Output and `$fs_uuid` is the first one.

At least run this to update your Grub:

```
$ grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

After reboot your Grub should contain the Entry for Windows, for more information about how to configure your Grub see this [Page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB)